# Countdown in JavaScript with variable

Tags: javascript, timeout, countdown, easeljs, createjs

I'm using CreateJS / EaselJS building my content.

I want to insert a short delay until some extra content is available for the user. It is important to show the remaining time!

My solution:

```
myLabel.text = "5";
setTimeout(function(){ myLabel.text = "4";
 setTimeout(function(){ myLabel.text = "3";
  setTimeout(function(){ myLabel.text = "2";
   setTimeout(function(){ myLabel.text = "1";
    setTimeout(function(){
     myLabel.text = "0";
     myButton.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
    }, 1000);
   }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
 }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

Is that possible with shorter code?

Bonus: Pass a variable as countdown duration (ex. 5000 for 5 sec.)

I hope for a quick answer, Simon

Comment: Quick answer: Use `setInterval()`.

Comment: @JohnBupit That should work! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `setInterval` instead:

```
var myNumber = 5;
myLabel.text = myNumber;
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
     myLabel.text = --myNumber;
     if (myNumber === 0) {
         myButton.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
         clearInterval(myInterval);
     }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the decrement function when you want to start the countdown.

```
var remaining = 5;

function decrement(){
    myLabel.text = remaining;
    remaining--;
    if(remaining >= 0){
        setTimeout(decrement, 1000);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a countdown ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/2y65mojg/)):

```
<div id="myLabel"></div>

var myLabel = document.getElementById('myLabel');

function countdown(duration) {
    myLabel.innerText = duration;

    if(duration > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            countdown(duration - 1);
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        myButton.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
    }       
}

countdown(8);
```

Comment: Why run a timeout after a timeout? When the timeout finishes, it will execute the function and it will take some ms before the next timeout gets queued in the event loop. interval will keep the function executing without the need to push it again to the event loop.

Comment: setInterval and setTimeout are not accurate time keepers. Counting down x seconds is not time critical, and setTimeout will add the function to the javascript queue where it's convenient for the system to run, where setInterval will try to run it whenever it can. In other words - this is what I prefer, and if setInterval makes your life better, then good for you :)